# Convex hull of points on sphere: open hemisphere condition

Tags: metric-spaces, convex-geometry, geodesic, spherical-geometry

I've read in several places that the convex hull of a subset of the sphere is *not* the whole sphere if and only if the subset is contained in an open hemisphere, but I'm not sure how to prove it. Does anyone know a proof?

By the sphere, I mean the unit sphere in any finite dimension, endowed with its intrinsic metric. By convex hull of a subset, I mean the smallest set containing that subset that is closed under taking shortest paths between points.

CLARIFICATION

Everything in this question is occurring inside the unit sphere, i.e., in the metric space $\mathbb{S}^n$, endowed with its intrinsic metric measured by great circle arc length. When I say convex hull of a subset $A\subseteq\mathbb{S}^n$, I *do not* mean convex hull in the Euclidean space containing $\mathbb{S}^n$; I mean the smallest subset $C_A$ of $\mathbb{S}^n$ that contains $A$ and such that, for any pair of points in $C_A$, any shortest path in $\mathbb{S}^n$ (i.e., piece of a great circle of length at most $\pi$) joining those two points is contained in $C_A$. To belabour the point, the unit ball is completely out of scope here; everything is a subset of $\mathbb{S}^n$. This is not Euclidean geometry; perhaps I picked the wrong tags?

Comment: By "whole sphere", I assume you mean "ball". I think your proposition is not true though. The convex hull of $\ T = \{ (x,y,z): x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = 1,\ z \leq \frac{1}{2} \}\ $ is $\ \{ (x,y,z): x^2 + y^2 + z^2 \leq 1,\ z \leq \frac{1}{2} \}\ $ which is not the unit ball. Maybe there is a miscommunication here, which could be clarified by you providing more explicit definitions of terms used.

Comment: Adding to the previous comment, I think this can be the case if by sphere we understand just the boundary of the ball, and using spherical segments for convexity, that is, joining points along the corresponding geodesic.

Comment: If you take $X={}$  the set having as elements the 4 summits of a regular tetrahedron inscribed in the sphere, then the convex hull of $X$ is that polyhedron, and _different from the whole ball_. On the other hand $X$ is not included in any hemisphere. (Or did I miss something?)

Comment: Adam’s and jp’s comments assume I meant convex hull in Euclidean space; I did not.  GReyes has the right idea! I have added a clarification to the question. Hopefully it makes sense now.

Comment: @jpboucheron If we take your example for $X$ and take the convex hull in the sense I mean (via geodesics on the surface of the sphere), we get the whole sphere.

Comment: Carefully reading my original post, I realise now it was not at all clear that I meant everything to be a subset of the sphere. Sorry!

Comment: @TomSharpe Indeed I had not understood the question. What happens if you take, as subset of $\mathbb{S}^n$, a great circle $\mathscr{C}$? If I'm not mistaken, this subset is “convex” and its convex hull is thus ${}\subsetneq\mathbb{S}^n$. However no open hemisphere includes $\mathscr{C}$.

Comment: A great circle is not convex in the sense I’ve given, because it contains a pair of antipodes; let me explain. The strict definition of convexity I’ve given above requires that, for any pair of points in the subset, *any* shortest path joining them must be contained in the subset. For a pair of antipodes, there are infinitely many shortest paths joining them (all of length $\pi$) whose union is the whole of $\mathbb{S}^n$. Therefore, the convex hull (in the sense given above) of a pair of antipodes is all of $\mathbb{S}^n$.

Comment: Yes, of course. Sorry.